# Place a button after an input and show it's password in plain text

Tags: javascript

I have managed to achieve this action through this:

```js
function togglePasswordVisibility($pw, on, id) {
  $pw.attr('type', on ? 'password' : 'text');
  $('[data-id=' + id + '] > i').toggleClass('fa-eye-slash fa-eye');
 }

 // $("#pass-on").after('<div class="input-group-append"><span class="password-button password-button-main"><i class="fas fa-eye-slash"></i></span></div>');

 $('[data-id]').on('click', function() {
  var id = $(this).data('id'),
   $pw = $('#' + id);

  togglePasswordVisibility($pw, false, id);

  setTimeout(function() {
   togglePasswordVisibility($pw, true, id);
  }, 800);
 });
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="input-group">
       <input type="password" id="pass-on" title="<?php echo $user->valid_password_error; ?>" class="form-control" name="txt_upass" placeholder="Enter Password" autocomplete="off" value="" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('<?php echo $user->password_error; ?>')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" required />
     <label>Password</label>
     <div class="input-group-append">
         <span class="password-button password-button-main" data-id="pass-on"><i class="fas fa-eye-slash"></i></span>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group progress jquery-result-1" style="height: 10px;">


     <div class="form-group input-group">
      <input type="password" id="pass-verify-on" title="<?php echo $user->valid_password_error; ?>" class="form-control" name="txt_upass_ok" placeholder="Retype Password" autocomplete="off" value="" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('<?php echo $user->password_error; ?>')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" required />
      <label>Retype Password</label>
      <div class="input-group-append">
          <span class="password-button password-button-verify" data-id="pass-verify-on"><i class="fas fa-eye-slash"></i></span>
        </div>
     </div>
```

But I would like to place the password button from within the function using the commented line with the `after` callback and making it apply the same effect. Right now the button correlates with the input through the association of data-id and id. If I would to place it inside the function I would have to get rid of the data-id and still make it act individually on each input, I just can't figure how. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first create the `i` element and add a click event handler to it dynamically while you wrap it inside the `div` and `span` and add it to the document.

As you use jQuery, I would suggest using it for creating each individual element, providing it with attributes using jQuery methods.

Here is how you could do it:

```js
function togglePasswordVisibility($pw, on, $eye) {
    $pw.attr('type', on ? 'password' : 'text');
    $eye.toggleClass('fa-eye-slash fa-eye');
}

$("[type=password]").each(function () {
    var $pw = $(this);
    var $eye = $("<i>").addClass("fas fa-eye-slash").click(function () {
        togglePasswordVisibility($pw, false, $eye);
        setTimeout(function() {
            togglePasswordVisibility($pw, true, $eye);
        }, 800);
    });
    $pw.parent().append(
        $("<div>").addClass("input-group-append").append(
            $("<span>").addClass("password-button password-button-main").append($eye)
        )
    );
});
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="input-group">
    <input type="password" id="pass-on" title="<?php echo $user->valid_password_error; ?>" class="form-control" name="txt_upass" placeholder="Enter Password" autocomplete="off" value="" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('<?php echo $user->password_error; ?>')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" required />
    <label for="pass-on">Password</label>
</div>
                
<div class="form-group input-group">
    <input type="password" id="pass-verify-on" title="<?php echo $user->valid_password_error; ?>" class="form-control" name="txt_upass_ok" placeholder="Retype Password" autocomplete="off" value="" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('<?php echo $user->password_error; ?>')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" required />
    <label for="pass-verify-on">Retype Password</label>
</div>
```

Comment: You are freaking genius. Thanks a lot, you are awesome! :)

Comment: You're welcome ;-)